# How reset the user password in django

Tags: django, django-forms

**I have make canteen invoice making app and also admin can create user, update user and change the user's password**
**but I don't why admin user can't reset the user's password when I'm change password Django throw error message 'A user with that username already exists.' **

**form.py**

```
class PasswordChange_Form(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username","password1","password2"]
        widgets = {
                "username":forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Username', 'readonly':'readonly'}),
                "password1":forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',"placeholder":"Password"}),
                "password2":forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Confirm Password'}),
        }
```

**View.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def UserChangePassword(request,pk):
    id = User.objects.get(id = pk)
    user_id =request.user
    heading_name = "user"
    rights, main_heading, page_menu, form_btn_data = RightLoader(user_id, heading_name)
    try:
        auth_check = rights.form_btn.get(heading_name = heading_name, btn_type = "Password")# fetch form btn right
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = PasswordChange_Form(request.POST, instance=id)
            try:
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    form = PasswordChange_Form(instance=id)
                    #update_session_auth_hash(request, )  # Important!
                    messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            except:
                    messages.error(request,str(form.errors))
        else:
            form = PasswordChange_Form(instance=id)
        context = {
            'form':form,
            'page_menu':page_menu,  
            'main_heading':main_heading,
            'btn_type':'fa fa-regular fa-plus',
            'title':'iCateen | User',
            'page_title':'Password Change',
            'tree_title_1':'User',
            'tree_url':'user',
            'tree_title_2':'Add Form',
            'view':'yes',
        }
        return render(request, 'base/user/change_password.html',context)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

**Admin user can change user's password ?**

Comment: I am confused first you say admin can't change password then you say can. You question seems confusing.

Comment: I want make admin user can reset the user's password.

Comment: as per my view.py it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Your form is inheriting from the [UserCreationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/59f475470494ce5b8cbff816b1e5dafcbd10a3a3/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L149) class

```
class PasswordChange_Form(UserCreationForm):
```

If you look at the linked code for that class you will see it raises an error if the username exists as it is trying to create a new user

Instead, try a normal model form for the user class:

```
class PasswordChange_Form(forms.ModelForm):
```

That will give you just a single password field as it is tied to the user model. You can add an extra field by the following method

```
class PasswordChange_Form(forms.ModelForm):
  password2 = forms.CharField()
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["username","password","password2"]
```

This will show you the current hashed password code in the `password` field. If that's a problem, you can do the same thing with a password1 field, eg:

```
class PasswordChange_Form(forms.ModelForm):
  
  password1 = forms.CharField()
  password2 = forms.CharField()
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["username","password1","password2"]
```

And then update your view for the submitted form

```
if form.is_valid():
   form.instance.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
   form.save
```

NB: Using set_password() rather than just saving the field ensures the new password also gets hashed.

Comment: When I'm add the 'class PasswordChange_Form(forms.ModelForm)' Django terminal throw the error = " django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (password2, password1) specified for User "

Comment: I've expanded the answer to handle some changes you will need when you use a model form.

Comment: I'm change the code above mention but problem is that when I'm load the form it's show me unreadable field

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: When load the form password fields show unreadable text ?

Comment: That sounds like a whole different question. You might like to ask it separately and provide the HTML for the form.

Comment: No it's different question.

Comment: What you are seeing is the current hashed user password stored securely in the database.  I've updated with a workaround for that also.

Answer (score -1):

Hey SamSparx I'll change my code as per you guide but form look like this

```
class PasswordChange_Form(forms.ModelForm):
  password2 = forms.CharField()
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["username","password","password2"]
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).